# Placing Day O in exact place of where default calendar is placed in Menu bar

Tags: calendar, menu-bar

I am using [Day-O](https://shauninman.com/archive/2011/10/20/day_o_mac_menu_bar_clock) in place of Mac's default clock in the menu bar. But now Day-O is placed in the left as shown below:-

[image]

Is there a way I can drag Day-O to the same location as default Mac Clock in Menu bar as shown below:-

[image]

I am using Mac OS Sierra 10.12.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Holding down the <kbd>⌘ command</kbd> key you can drag items on your menu bar in order to reposition them.

Comment: Cou can command-drag Day-O to the right of every icon in the menu bar *except* the notification center icon